# Windows 7 - add new file type extension

Tags: windows, associations

I want to add a file type extension called .phtml to the set association page.
In this case I want eclipse to automatically open Zend .phtml files

Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations

Comment: Please delete this question and repost it on superuser.com.

Comment: If you want to do this programmatically, what language will you be doing this in? Please provide more information, or take Jim's advice.

Comment: Shouldn't the question just be migrated? (something you can vote for, but neither I or roger rover can)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do this programmatically.

This information is stored in the Windows Registry, under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  You need a key for the extension (.phtml), with the default being a basic descriptor (something like "ZendFile").

Then you need a key for that descriptor ("ZendFile"), with a subkey of "shell", which will have a subkey of "Open", and a subkey of "command".  The default for "command" will need to be the command line to execute.

Comment: Depends on the programming language you are using.

Comment: Then you've posted the the wrong forum. This is a programming forum. You can get to this functionality through Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Command prompt.
- Type

> assoc .phtml=
>
> Open Control Panel - Default Programs - Associate a file type or protocol with a program
>
> Scroll to .phtml, click Change program... and choose Eclipse